# Adding a local jar into mvn clean package result

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I'm building a SonarQube plugin and I need to use Maven to achieve it, I must use the goals clean package to create the jar file that acts as the plugin. My problem is that I need to load either a local jar file, which didn't worked as I tried using: `<systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/epsilon-1.3-core.jar</systemPath>` to load it as a dependency and Maven wasn't able to resolve it or I must load three external projects which are at my workspace but I don't know how to tell maven to include them.

Could someone help me to do this? I'd really appreciate it! Using my own Maven repo (with Nexus for example) isn't an option.

Comment: Did you try adding the `http://ticsw.github.io/mvn-repo/` custom repository? And don't use the `system` scope. And it seems version 1.3 doesn't exist, it is 1.2.

Comment: 1.3 exists (interim version) and that repo doesn't seems to be active anymore. I also need 1.3 due to the new api

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a local maven repository loading the plugins of Epsilon as jar files, it's a temp solution while the Epsilon Team setup a maven repo.